# Extracting 6 digit number from file name using regex

Tags: python, regex

I've written some Python code that parses filenames and metadata from a directory. There is no consistent naming convention for the files but each filename includes a six digit number that I need to extract. The only consistency I can find in the naming convention is the use of underscores.

I have been able to extract these numbers rather successfully using the code below, but there are a few files where this is not working, and I am trying to understand what I need to tweak to capture the last few.

```
df = new_df_meta['file']
len(df)
r = re.compile('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
n = re.compile(r'\b\d{6,6}\b')

newlist = list(filter(r.findall, df))
len(newlist)



newlistres0 = [(sub.split('_')[2]) for sub in newlist]
newlistres1 = [(sub.split('_')[1]) for sub in newlist]
newlistres2 = [(sub.split('_')[0]) for sub in newlist]



newlistres = newlistres0 + newlistres1 + newlistres2
```

Below is an example of one of the remaining file names where I haven't been able to successful extract the six digit number (565244):

09.10_ad epx_SI544015_565244_en12_20_2020_FY2019_44781_08251594.pdf

I have tried to add the line of code below, but I get an error message that the **"list index is out of range"**

```
newlistres3 = [(sub.split('_')[3]) for sub in newlist]
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The error I am recieving:

```
 IndexError                                
 Traceback (most recent call last) 
 <ipython-input-146-20c18449951e> in <module>
      13 newlistres1 = [(sub.split('_')[1]) for sub in newlist]
      14 newlistres2 = [(sub.split('_')[0]) for sub in newlist]
 ---> 15 newlistres3 = [(sub.split('_')[3]) for sub in newlist]
      16 # newlistres4 = [(sub.split('_')[4]) for sub in newlist]
      17 
 
 <ipython-input-146-20c18449951e> in <listcomp>(.0)
      13 newlistres1 = [(sub.split('_')[1]) for sub in newlist]
      14 newlistres2 = [(sub.split('_')[0]) for sub in newlist]
 ---> 15 newlistres3 = [(sub.split('_')[3]) for sub in newlist]
      16 # newlistres4 = [(sub.split('_')[4]) for sub in newlist]
      17 
 
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: maybe use normal `for`-loop and run `parts = sub.split('_')` and then you can use `print()` to see what you get in parts. If six digits is last element then you can use `[-1]`. If some names may produce less parts (`len(parts) <= 3`) then you should use `if len(parts) > 3: newlistres3.append(parts[3])`

Comment: in code you could create DataFrame with example data so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you would use normla `for`-loop then you could use `print()` to see for what filenames you get error.

Comment: I believe all you need is `new_df_meta['codes'] = new_df_meta['file'].str.extract(r'_(\d{6})_').fillna("")`

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `\b` will *never* match with `_`

You'll have to search for underscore followed by 6 digits followed by underscore, then extract the matching digits only.

```py
searcher = re.compile(r"(?:_|^)(\d{6})(?:_|$)")
```

- `(?:)` indicates *non-capturing group*
- `_|^` match a preceding underscore *or* start of string
- `_|$` match a trailing underscore *or* end of string

Now you just iterate through the list of files; no need to go fancy with `filter` and such.

```py
newlistres = []
for filename in df:
    m = searcher.search(filename)
    if m is None:
        continue
    newlistres.append(m.group(1))
```